# How can I create an entity reference exposed filter?

Tags: views, 8

How can I create an entity reference exposed filter?

The only option I have is input of type text.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional module for that:

[Entity Reference Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_exposed_filters)

This might also help: [Views field select filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_select_filter)

I'm not sure if this one supports exposed or only normal filters: [Views Entity Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/verf)

Answer (score 0):

You can reated a hook_form_FORM_ID_form_alter() in my module.module file.Below is my code example:

```
function module_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-view-name-page-1') {

    if (array_key_exists('field_name_target_id', $form)) {

      // Rewrite the default 'All' option
      if (!empty($form['field_name_target_id']['#options']['All'])) {
        $option_default = ['All' => t('- Any -')];
      }

      $options = $form['field_name_target_id']['#options'];

      // Ensure that only terms that are used in the view
      // are displayed in the filter
      $connection = Database::getConnection();
      $query = $connection->select('node__field_name', 'vocabulary');
      $query->join('node_field_data', 'n', 'n.nid = vocabulary.entity_id');
      $query->fields('vocabulary', ['field_name_target_id']);
      $query->fields('n', ['status']);
      $query->condition('vocabulary.bundle', 'nodebundle');
      $query->condition('n.status', 1);
      $data = $query->distinct()->execute();

      $results = array_flip($data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 'field_name_target_id'));
      $options = array_intersect_key($options, $results);

      // Rebuild the option select with the term values and the all option
      $form['field_name_target_id']['#options'] = $option_default + $options;
    }
  }
}
```